# Prevent conversion of `&lt;` into `<` in hxt

Tags: haskell, hxt

TL;DR: I need to stop hxt from converting `&lt;` into `<` in the conversion between `String` and `XMLTree`, and vice-versa.

I'm using hxt to parse XML documents.

In the documents I need to parse, users can put anything they want in specific tags (for the sake of the example, let's call them `<mytag>` and `</mytag>`), but they have to escape any HTML inside. So, instead of writing `<mytag><b>text</b></mytag>` they have to write `<mytag>&lt;b&gt;text&lt;/b&gt;</mytag>`.

I don't control the format, I just have to parse it.

Specifically, I have to load the document into a `String`, use a user-provided xpath-query (given also as a `String`) to select portions of the document, convert the matching results to a list of `Strings`, and do the same thing again individually for each result to extract the sub-portions I need. For example, having:

```
<mytags>
<mytag><attribute type="somethingIrecognize">&lt;b&gt;text1&lt;/b&gt;</attribute><attribute type="someOtherThing">fdfdjskadjfk</attribute></mytag>
<mytag><attribute type="somethingIrecognize">&lt;b&gt;text2&lt;/b&gt;</attribute><attribute type="someOtherThing">fdfdjskadjfk</attribute></mytag>
</mytags>
```

The first XPath string (which has to be given as argument to my function as a Haskell `String`), has to first produce a list of tags. In this case, for example, applying `"//mytags/*"` first should produce:

```
[ "<mytag><attribute type=\"somethingIrecognize\">&lt;b&gt;text1&lt;/b&gt;</attribute><attribute type=\"someOtherThing\">value1</attribute></mytag>"
, "<mytag><attribute type=\"somethingIrecognize\">&lt;b&gt;text2&lt;/b&gt;</attribute><attribute type=\"someOtherThing\">value2</attribute></mytag>"
]
```

Now I can run the second search individually on each result to extract the data I need. For example, applying `"//mytag/attribute[contains(@type,"somethingIRecognize")]/text()"` to the first value should give me:

```
&lt;b&gt;text1&lt;/b&gt;
```

Sometimes, users include HTML that is absolutely broken, but I still want to keep it literally the way they wrote it. For example, they might write (without a closing tag `</b>`):

```
<mytags>
<mytag>
 <attribute type="somethingIrecognize">&lt;b&gt;text1</attribute>
 <attribute type="someOtherThing">value1</attribute>
</mytag>
</mytags>
```

I'm finding an issue using HXT where, when I read the XML, select what I need (with xpath) and then turn it into a `String` for further processing at a later stage, the `&lt;b&gt;text&lt;/b&gt;` has been converted into `<b>text</b>`.

This makes later processors choke because, when the inner HTML is very broken, and no matter how hard I try to disable error detection, HXT still complains about missing closing tags, etc. and won't let me process it further.

In case it matters, I'm using this `xshow` to turn each result back into a string so that I can process it later with a second xpath query: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.22/docs/Text-XML-HXT-DOM-ShowXml.html#v:xshow

Is there a way to prevent that conversion?

Comment: It appears that this is happening at the point of reading the document. If I run the first query and print the trees that come out, hxt has converted the `&lt;b&gt;` into a `<b>` already in the argument to the `XText` value. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Substitution for default XML entities (`&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, `&apos;` and `&quot;`) occurs within the low-level parser and can't be disabled, unless you're willing to patch a custom version of `hxt`.

However, if you use `xshowEscapeXml` in place of `xshow`, it will escape `&` and `<` in text (though not `>` or the others), which is typically going to be enough for XML to correctly re-parse the output as XML.